# Dart strange behavior in fixed length multidimensional list

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a little bit new to dart and wanted to create multi dimensional list which will be filled in a loop but noticed strange behavior:

```
import 'dart:core';

void main() {
  final List<List<int>> list = List.filled(3, []);
  list[0].add(1);
  list[1].add(2);
  list[2].add(3);
  print(list);
}
```

the output is `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]` I expected to see `[[1], [2], [3]]` An explanation of why it works this way and a possible way to fix it is very appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because **.filled()** doesn't create a new value to fill and just uses the same one for all items in the list.
So all 3 lists reference the same list object.
Use **.generate()** to create separate lists:

```dart
final List<List<int>> list = List.generate(3, (_) => <int>[]);
```

And don't hesitate to read the docs for List, because it basically tells the same thing :) [List.filled Docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/List/List.filled.html)

> All elements of the created list share the same fill value.
> You can use List.generate to create a list with a fixed length and a new object at each position.

Comment: Thank you, though same way but couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 1):

From [`List.filled` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/List/List.filled.html):

> All elements of the created list share the same fill value.
>
> ```dart
> var shared = List.filled(3, []);
> shared[0].add(499);
> print(shared);  // => [[499], [499], [499]]
> ```
>
> You can use List.generate to create a list with a fixed length and a new object at each position.
>
> ```dart
> var unique = List.generate(3, (_) => []);
> unique[0].add(499);
> print(unique); // => [[499], [], []]
> ```